# PyQt5: how do I use a variable output from one button for another button?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qfiledialog

I am trying to implement a GUI on a python code using PyQt5. I figured out how to use buttons and how to connect them to functions.

Button b3 calls the function "SelectFile"

```
self.b3.clicked.connect(self.SelectFile)

def SelectFile(self):
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Select file", "", "TMY3 files (*.epw)", options=options)[0]
            print(filename)
            return filename
```

The problem I have is that I want "SelectFile" to return the path of a file, and then use that path for another function called by another button. How can I do that?

For example,

```
self.b1.clicked.connect(self.btn_clk)

 def btn_clk(self):
    sender = self.sender()
    if sender.text() =='Print':
        test = filename
        print(test)
```

"filename" is not passed to "btn_clk" and I don't know how to do that.
I tried to input "filename" in the definition of "btn_clk" and other attempts as well, but nothing worked.

Thanks

Comment: Create a variable and assign it the value you want to save.

Answer (score 0):

```
def SelectFile(self):
    options = QFileDialog.Options()
    options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
    filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Select file", "", "TMY3 files (*.epw)", options=options)[0]
        print(filename)
        self.b1_filename = filename
        return filename

self.b1.clicked.connect(self.btn_clk)

def btn_clk(self):
    sender = self.sender()
    if sender.text() =='Print':
        test = self.b1_filename
        print(test)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just store it in the class, and it's ready to go. Use the code below to test. You can adjust to suit with your code.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import sys

class TestSelectFile(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.selectfilebutton = QPushButton('Select file')
        self.printpathbutton = QPushButton('Press to print')

        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.selectfilebutton)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.printpathbutton)

        self.selectfilebutton.clicked.connect(self.getpath)
        self.printpathbutton.clicked.connect(self.printpath)

    def getpath(self):
        self.path = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,caption='Get a path from',filter='All Files(*.*)')

    def printpath(self):
        print(self.path)



app = QApplication(sys.argv)
dialog = TestSelectFile()
dialog.show()
app.exec_()
```